# Using parameters with for loop in verilog for bit selection

Tags: parameters, for-loop, verilog, hdl

I am designing some hardware in Verilog, but in an effort to keep things flexible, I am using parameters to set widths so that I can modify widths as needed without modifying code.  One problem I have run into is in a section of code where I want to be able to do a parallel write into multiple cells.

```
parameter DATA_WIDTH = 16;
parameter BUFFER_SIZE = 16;
parameter LOAD_WIDTH = DATA_WIDTH*BUFFER_SIZE;

input [LOAD_WIDTH-1:0] i_load_data;

reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]    r_data_buf[BUFFER_SIZE-1:0];

...

always@(posedge clk) begin
....
    else if (i_load_flag) begin
        for(i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i = i + 1)
            r_data_buf[i] <= i_load_data[i * BUFFER_SIZE + BUFFER_SIZE - 1:i * BUFFER_SIZE];
    end
end
```

I need to keep r_data_buf as an array because of the way the data has to be read.  It is also not clear to me why verilog doesn't like this code since everything is a constant at compile time or how I can fix it and still get the behavior I want.

Comment: It would probably help if you could say what verilog doesn't like (error messages?, synthesis failure?, simulation failure?), but just based on speculation I think that most synthesizers would implement an array like that as a ram or latch array, and you would not typically be able to write multiple locations at the same time. (There's only one addr/data bus going into the RAM, so you can't cram two writes into it on the same cycle).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Verilog compiler is unhappy because it sees i_load_data[x:y] where both x and y depend on parameters so it is worried that this might result in a changing width (although in your case it is impossible).

There are a couple of easy ways to fix this:

1. Use the +: operator to specify the width.  (I've also changed BUFFER_SIZE to DATA_WIDTH because that looked like a typo.)  In this form you give the index of the LSB and the width of the data you wish to select.

   ```
   r_data_buf[i] <= i_load_data[i * DATA_WIDTH  +: DATA_WIDTH];
   ```
2. Use an additional for loop to set each bit individually

   ```
   for(i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i = i + 1)
   begin
       for(j = 0; j < DATA_WIDTH; j = j + 1)
       begin
           r_data_buf[i][j] <= i_load_data[i * DATA_WIDTH  + j];
       end
   end
   ```

Comment: 1 completely solved my problem.  I have never seen that syntax but it is definitely useful.  Also, yes, that was a typo.

Comment: Happy to help :)  You may also be interested in the similar operator -: in which you give the index of the MSB and the width of the data instead.  In this case it is not as good because you would write something like "i_load_data[i * DATA_WIDTH + DATA_WIDTH-1 -: DATA_WIDTH]"